# Is it possible to get a webpage that requires JS in Golang?

Tags: javascript, go, server

Creating a micro service that gets couple websites main pages html. 
One of them performs a check for enabled JS and redirects to error page 
if no JS was detected.

Is there a way around it with Golang?

EDIT: attempted to play with [this package (JavaScript interpreter)](https://github.com/robertkrimen/otto) but with no luck..

EDIT2: its 2020, moved to use js [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer)

It uses embedded browser and is a very mature and packed with utilities library. for complex web apps embedded browser is really the only one to go

For backends written in other the js I would still use 'Puppeteer' as a micro service

hope this helps anyone  in the future

thanks

Comment: since go never went upstream in major browsers its highly doubtable you can use go without compiling it to javascript first anyways.

Comment: It depends how the site checks for JS. Do you have some code example?

Comment: @apxp you mean the sites code? don't have that, as for my code its a precise  duplicate of the request sent from the browser (headers wise)

Comment: The site's code would be the relevant part. How to get around it depends on how it's being done in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Like Gonzalez mentioned earlier, PhantomJS is a good choice. But there are some things I would like to clarify, first there is a problem using the phantomgo repository on Linux as the developer doesn't provide the binary of the PanthomJS for Linux.

The way this repository is used should be using the following instructions:

1. `go get github.com/k4s/phantomgo`
2. `go get github.com/k4s/webrowser`
3. Download the pre-compiled binary for your platform of PhantomJS on [this page](https://phantomjs.org/download.html).
4. Add the binary to the `$GOPATH/src/github.com/k4s/phantomgo/phantomgojs` folder.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"

    . "github.com/k4s/webrowser"
)

func main() {
    p := &Param{
        Method:       "GET",
        Url:          "http://google.com",
        Header:       http.Header{"Cookie": []string{"your cookie"}},
        UsePhantomJS: true,
    }
    brower := NewWebrowse()
    resp, err := brower.Download(p)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(body))
    fmt.Println(resp.Cookies())
}
```

Comment: thanks, a legit answer for this question so marking it as selected for future comers. As for my self - a lot of time passed since.. for scraping I prefer to use js [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) these days.. if the server is in `node` great if in `Go` or any other language (for me) its better to create a micro service with Puppeteer. it uses its own browser and is a very mature and packed scraper solution.. my 2 cents

Comment: Nice to know about that. PhantomJS is about to be discontinued so I’m glad that you shared the information about Puppeteer. I myself use Go for scrapping and I was looking for a embedded browser solution and Chromium + Godet also seems to be a reasonable solution.

Comment: Oh sure, happy to help :) try out Puppeteer they solve sooo many things that will really long time to implement yourself - and for complex websites/ apps an embedded browser is the only way to go, as there are so many requests and responses going on that doing all of those manually will be a living (and un sustainable) nightmare

Answer (score 1):

Try PhantomJS for Go https://github.com/k4s/phantomgo

I tried it once and it worked for me, maybe it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Headless Chrome.
Here is an [example](https://github.com/YijinLiu/headless-chromium).